# что значит "лови добавку"?

Tags: значения

Я понимаю, что эти слова значат отдельно, но значение целой фразы мне не ясно.

Comment: Контекст давать не забывайте.

Answer (score 4):

"Лови́ доба́вку" зна́чит "вот тебе́ ещё". "Лови́" (разгово́рное) зна́чит "держи́, получи́".